# How to fetch data only if both user are friend from sql server

Tags: sql, join, sql-in

Here is my database structure.
User table
-user_id
-fname
-lname

profile table
-profile_user_id
-profile_id
-profile_id

friend_request table
-id
-from_id
-to_id
-status
my query is
SELECT fname,lname,profile FROM user LEFT JOIN profile ON user.user_id = profile.profile_id WHERE(SELECT status FROM friend_request WHERE status = 'friend')

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and an approach database tag.  A clear explanation of what you are trying to accomplish would also help.

Comment: Please be careful with undoing helpful formatting improvements by wellmeaning other users. I think the change you undid was a good one. Demonstrating that you do not appreciate people spending effort on improving your post is likely to be detrimental for finding somebody who helps you with your actual problem.

Comment: For the best way to represent a suitably tailored toy database have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info and the MRE concept described there. Or at least at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 SELECT fname,lname,profile FROM user 
 INNER JOIN profile ON user.user_id = profile.profile_id 
 INNER join user 'friend' on friend.user_id = = profile.profile_id
 INNER JOIN friend_request ON friend_request.from_id = user.user_id and  friend_request.to_id = friend.user_id 
 WHERE status = 'friend'
```